# When copying a page the slug field is not updated properly

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

When I copy a page in TYPO3 10.4.9 and insert it as a subpage of a different page in the same site the slug is not updated properly. It stays the same with a suffix "-1". I would expect the slug to be regenerated based on the new rootline. Anybody who can confirm this behaviour? I would have thought that this bug is already be fixed: [Copying a page copies the slug without making it unique?](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87697?tab=changesets)

Example: Page *mypage* with slug */somepage/mypage* is copied and inserted as subpage of page *otherpage*. The slug of the copied page is set to */somepage/mypage-1*. Expected slug value would be */otherpage/mypage*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extension [sluggi](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/sluggi/) in version >= 2.0.0. to change the default behaviour of TYPO3 10. With this extension installed slugs of pages are updated on copy according to the new rootline.

(There is a bug report addressing the default behaviour of TYPO3 10: [Slugs are not maintained reasonable when copying pages/pagetrees](https://forge.typo3.org/issues/90405))

Answer (score 0):

The described behaviour is correct. URLs are not updated automatically, as it may be desirable to continue using the old URL.
The addition of a number, however, is automatic and is necessary because the URL '/somepage/mypage' now exists twice.

Comment: I cannot believe that this is the intended behaviour. If I would be _moving_ a page it makes some sense to keep the slug value. But why would I want keep the slug if I _copy_ a page to a another parent page? Why would I want to keep the name of the old parent page in the slug instead of regenerating it with the the name of the new parent page?